# problem with mysql update - its change all rows

Tags: mysql

I have mysql history table that set like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
 )
```

I ran this line:

```
 ALTER TABLE history ADD COLUMN removed int(11) DEFAULT '0';
```

but when i run this:

```
update history set removed=1 where user_id=1599;
```

**I get all rows changed with random values and and date reset to now!**

I think i'v error in table but I dont now what. the set seem fine....

Comment: 'I get all rows changed with random values and and date reset to now!' - not with this code you don't have you checked triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the user_id is Default to '0'

and here you're overwriting the values in user_id, it's messing up the table

So just do

```
Create table history ( user_id int(11));
```

remove " Default '0' ".

Comment: but if i want set default how can i do it?

Comment: @Fox user_id can't be default i guess, because it's unique for everyone right